# Foreign ID in SQL tables to link one table to another

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL code which links users to items based on tutorials:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_email` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_access_level` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_activation_hash` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_password_reset_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_password_reset_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_failed_logins` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_last_failed_login` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_registration_datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `user_registration_ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
 `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `item_title` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_location` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_description` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `item_status` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd011

I'm getting a bit confused about how to link the items to the user. It seems like I need something called a foreign key on the items, a bit like this in my item table:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(ID)
```

I can't seem to get it to compile and query successfully. Can anyone please show me the right way to associate the items with the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `user_id` column to the `items` table along with the constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_email` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_access_level` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_activation_hash` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_password_reset_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_password_reset_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_failed_logins` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `user_last_failed_login` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_registration_datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `user_registration_ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
 `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int unsigned,
 `item_title` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_location` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_description` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `item_datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `item_status` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ce2df).

I should point out a few other things:

- Pay attention to the database engine you are using.  MyISAM doesn't actually enforce the relationship.
- Having weird dates as the default value is probably less useful than just using `NULL`.
- I'm not sure if there is a value to having explicit collations for every character definition, unless your database is going to be supporting a wide variety of collations.
- Don't use single quotes for numeric constants.  So, if a value is declared as a `tinyint`, set the default ot `0` not `'0'` (this doesn't affect performance in a `CREATE TABLE` statement; it is just misleading).

Comment: Also probably use InnoDB instead of MyISAM.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski How come Michael? Would I need to change any of my PHP code in this regard?

Comment: @Jimmy MyISAM tables don't actually enforce foreign key constraints, though it's not a syntax error to define them. Your code doesn't need to change, only the create table statements. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Comment: Just a quick question Gordon. If I have COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci at the bottom of the table entry as a default do I need to have it on each line (i.e item_title line. Thank you for the help though, I will mark it as answered when it lets me.

Comment: @Jimmy . . . If you set the default collation for the table, then it applies to all the appropriate columns in the table with no explicit override.

Answer (score 1):

@GordonLindoff's solution is one method, but that assumes that each item belongs to exactly one user, and an item cannot be referenced by multiple users.  If you have a many-to-many relationship, where a user can have multiple items and an item can be referenced by multiple users, then you need a third table that links them together:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_item` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_item`,`item_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(item_id)
)ENGINE=Innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The Foreign Key constraints enforce that for every row in user_item that the user_id exists in users, and the item_id exists in items.  And as was mentioned in a previous comment, that you will need Innodb to have the foreign key constraints enforced.